# WSO2 Identity Server pattern clustering

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are in production with WSO2 Identity Server 5.8.0

We configured the system according to the pattern 1 as described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Setting+Up+Deployment+Pattern+1)

When we checked the *symlink* of config and governance we noticed that only config has a *symlink* icon as showed in this image

[image: SymLink Missing]

Moreover we registered some Service Providers but in the management interface they are not listed although they are present in the table. This seems to be related to the fact that we changed the WSO2 IS admin username after we created the Service Providers and in the table sp_app there is the old username (I can't understand the reason)

Her our configurations about pattern-1. We are using postgreSQL DB.

What we did is the following:

- creation of db username_db. Here we executed the following SQL scripts

  - dbScripts/bps/bpel/create/postgresql.sql
  - dbScripts/content/postgresql.sql
  - dbScripts/identity/postgresql.sql
  - dbScripts/identity/uma/postgresql.sql
  - dbScripts/metrics/postgresql.sql
- creation of db wso2sharedregistry. Here we executed the sql contained in

  - dbScripts/postgresql.sql

We configigured the following datasource in the `master-datasources.xml` file

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">
    <providers>
        <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
    </providers>
    <datasources>
    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/usernameDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx:yyyy/username_db</url>
                    <username>username</username>
                    <password>username</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <!--<validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>-->
                </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_SHAREDREGISTRY_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2sharedbd</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx:yyyy/wso2sharedregistry</url>
                    <username>username</username>
                    <password>username</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <!--<validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>-->
                </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
    </datasources>
</datasources-configuration>
```

We configured the `registry.xml` in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<wso2registry>
    <currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
    <dbConfig name="wso2registry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>
    <dbConfig name="wso2sharedregistry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2sharedbd</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>
   <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.registry.RegistryPolicyHandler">
 <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.registry.RegistryPolicyMediaTypeMatcher">
 <property name="mediaType">application/xacml-policy+xml</property>
 </filter>
 </handler>
    <remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9443/registry">
        <id>instanceid</id>
        <dbConfig>wso2sharedregistry</dbConfig>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>false</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
    </remoteInstance>
    
    
    <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>instanceid</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
    </mount>
    
    <mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>instanceid</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/nodes</targetPath>
    </mount>

    <indexingConfiguration>
        <startIndexing>false</startIndexing>
        <startingDelayInSeconds>35</startingDelayInSeconds>
        <indexingFrequencyInSeconds>5</indexingFrequencyInSeconds>
        <!--number of resources submit for given indexing thread -->
        <batchSize>40</batchSize>
        <!--number of worker threads for indexing -->
        <indexerPoolSize>40</indexerPoolSize>
        <!-- location storing the time the indexing took place-->
        <lastAccessTimeLocation>/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime</lastAccessTimeLocation>
        <!-- the indexers that implement the indexer interface for a relevant media type/(s) -->
        <indexers>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.MSExcelIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.MSPowerpointIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.MSWordIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/msword"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PDFIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/pdf"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.XMLIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/xml"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.XMLIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/(.)+\+xml"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/swagger\+json"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/(.)+\+json"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="text/(.)+"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/x-javascript"/>
        </indexers>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion pathRegEx="/_system/config/repository/dashboards/gadgets/swfobject1-5/.*[.]html"/>
            <exclusion pathRegEx="/_system/local/repository/components/org[.]wso2[.]carbon[.]registry/mount/.*"/>
        </exclusions>
    </indexingConfiguration>
    <versionResourcesOnChange>false</versionResourcesOnChange>
    <!-- NOTE: You can edit the options under "StaticConfiguration" only before the
     startup. -->
    <staticConfiguration>
        <versioningProperties>true</versioningProperties>
        <versioningComments>true</versioningComments>
        <versioningTags>true</versioningTags>
        <versioningRatings>true</versioningRatings>
    </staticConfiguration>
</wso2registry>
```

Any tips in how we can:

- show the previously registered Service Providers
- create the correct registry symlink

Comment: When you create a service provider config, an internal role is created. Pattern is Application/<service provider name>. The users belonging to that role only can see the service provider configs. Check if the user who is checking this config is assigned to the service provider roles. If not assign them to make applications visible to those users.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena you saved my day :) Now I can see the SP. Then only missing thing now is the registry symlink. Thank you again really thank you